# Difference between atomic operator++ and atomic_fetch_add_explicit

Tags: c, multithreading, atomic

What is the difference between:

```
atomic_int s = 0;
++s; //does s++ work as well?
```

and:

```
atomic_int s = 0;
atomic_fetch_add_explicit(&s, 1, memory_order_relaxed);
```

Are both of them atomic increments?

Comment: From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic): Built-in increment and decrement operators and compound assignment are read-modify-write atomic operations with total sequentially consistent ordering (as if using memory_order_seq_cst). If less strict synchronization semantics are desired, the standard library functions may be used instead.

Comment: @Shawn So the 2 would be the same if I replaced `memory_order_relaxed` with `memory_order_seq_cst`?

Comment: @DarkAtom Yes, those would be equivalent. Atomics by default use the safest ordering.

Comment: Thanks! Also, is there any difference between a regular initialization (like in the example) and `atomic_init()` and `ATOMIC_INIT_VAR()`?